# How to access most recently inserted record in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

In my .net mvc app I'm posting to a server method and inserting a record during this method:

```
var MyVar = new ModelType();

await DbHelper.Insert(MyVar);
Debug.WriteLine(MyVar.ID);
```

As you can see in the example I try to access the ID value of the MyVar object AFTER it's inserted into a SQL table.  However the value is always 0 and my table is populated as expected.  I was thinking that the variable would be mapped to the record?  This works using EF but I'm thinking that might be some behind the scenes magic?

Comment: What is DbHelper? and if you are not using EF, what are you using?

Comment: It depends on the specific SQL database how to get the last inserted id. Check the documentation

Comment: @CodingYoshi DbHeper is just the class I wrote to handle all my data-access.  Another thing worth noting is that the the Insert function is functioning properly.  As for what ORM I'm using: it's Dapper.

Comment: Perhaps accessing the last inserted row of the table would be the wrong solution anyways?  What if two people are inserting into that table at the same time and one connection is slower, the slower connection would probably be referencing the wrong record in a scenario like this right?

Comment: I want to be able to access the record of the object that is inserted inside the server function, immediately following the insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Dapper, it has no support for out parameters. But inside your `DbHelper.Insert` method, make changes to your code so it returns the id of the inserted item. Here is an example:

```
string sql = @"
    INSERT INTO [SomeTable] ([SomeColumn]) VALUES (@SomeParameter);
    SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";
```

Please note the `SELECT` within the query. Then do this:

```
var id = connection.Query<int>(sql, new { SomeColumn = myColumn}).Single();
```